# eliminar una propiedad de un json con mongo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

tengo el siguente arreglo:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f982a5fe64d4c0315caebac"), 
    "baneado" : false, 
    "email" : "rodolfo.computacion+003@gmail.com", 
    "password" : "$2a$10$Q6Uk.OUVFmZAtREHnogEuOabPvnQlvQ15yKPxo/fFcZ5xEciYdOHu", 
    "nombre" : "Rodolfo", 
    "apellido" : "Rodriguez", 
    "propiedades" : [
        {
            "beta" : true
        }, 
        {
            "promociones" : {
                "activo" : true
            }
        }
    ], 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-10-27T14:10:39.108+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-10-27T14:14:55.096+0000"), 

}
```

y estoy tratando de eliminar a traves de una consulta mongo, aca el codigo

```
var promesaUser =  User.update({ _id: elemento._user }, { $pull: {  propiedades:{promociones: { $exists: true} }  } }).exec()
```

pero me da el siguiente error:

**error 1  MongoError: '$pull' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$pull: {: ...}}
at Function.MongoError.create (/home/rodolfo/desarrollo/api-backend-ecdf/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:45:10**

si alguien pudiese ayudarme de antemano gracias...estoy comenzando disculpen los errores

este es el esquema:

```
var Users = new Schema({

//module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', new Schema({


    email: {

        type: String,

        require: [true, 'Email requerido'],

        lowercase: true,

        unique: true

    },

    password: {

        type: String,

        require: [true, 'Contraseña requerida']

    },

    verificado: {

        type: Boolean,

        default: false

    },
    material: {

        type: String

    },

    dispositivos: {

        type: String

    },

    fecha_fin: {

        type: Date,

    },

    fecha_acuerdo : {

        type: Date,

    },
    nombre: {

        type: String

    },

    apellido: {

        type: String

    }
```

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users',Users);

no se como agregar promociones, disculpen comienzo en esto....

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar como tienes tu esquema? Por otro lado, el método [`update()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) ha sido marcado como [obsoleto](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#update) en Mongoose (v5.10.11). Por lo cual deberías utilizar `updateOne()` en este caso. Igualmente si puedes [edit] tu pregunta para ver cómo tienes el esquema de datos. Saludos

Comment: debo utilizar ese comando de mongo por versiones en el servidor, pero tenias razón no aparece en el esquema pero no se como arreglarlo, disculpa solo comienzo, gracias Mauricio...

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Mongo y de Mongoose utilizas?

Comment: oye @MauricioContreras te quiero dar las gracia, agregue propiedades al modelo y funciono perfecto, gracias por tu tiempo y tus conocimientos, estaba dandole ayer todo el dia,  sin ver ese detalle,gracias y bendiciones